# Python - UPDATE or INSERT to sqlite using dictionary

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I am trying to UPDATE or INSERT if not exist rows into sqlite table.
Can't manage to do this from python level using *executemany*

my **input csv** looks like this:

```
cfthostname,cftshortname,cftenv,cert_time
lx1234.pl.net,lx1234,tst,28/01/2021
plx169.net,plx169,tst,26/03/2021
sp2444445.net,sp2444445,prd,12/06/2021
```

my **db model**:

```
cfthostname,cftshortname,cftenv,cert_time
lx1234.pl.net,lx1234,tst,DD/MM/RRRR
plx169.net,plx169,tst,DD/MM/RRRR
sp2444445.net,sp2444445,prd,DD/MM/RRRR
```

what i need to do is:

1. UPDATE **cert_time** column if **cfthostname** in input csv matches **cfthostname** in db

2. INSERT all 4 columns if **cfthostname** does not exists in DB

**db_update.py**

```
import sqlite3
import csv

conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\db.sqlite3")
cursor = conn.cursor()
[...]
######---Import to DB---######
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS itpassed_host (cfthostname, cftshortname, cftenv, cert_time);")
with open('C:\csv\cfthosts.csv','rt') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    to_db = [(i['cfthostname'], i['cftshortname'], i['cftenv'], i['cert_time']) for i in dr]

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO itpassed_host (cfthostname, cftshortname, cftenv, cert_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT (cfthostname) DO UPDATE SET cert_time=excluded.cert_time;", to_db)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

i get

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error
```

i have sqlite 3.7.17

Comment: Assuming `cfthostname` is a primary key or has a unique index, if you update to a modern version of sqlite, you can use [ON CONFLICT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) like that. However, you're lacking the required constraint and are using a very outdated version of sqlite.

Comment: Is there any other way to do such UPDATE even ignoring INSERT(i can deal with insert in other way).

Comment: You can always do it in a couple of steps; First see if a particular row exists, and if so update it, if not, insert a new one.

Comment: donwloaded 3.29.0 version of sqlite and still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Use "WHERE True" to avoid this conflict:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO itpassed_host (cfthostname, cftshortname, cftenv, cert_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) **WHERE True** ON CONFLICT (cfthostname) DO UPDATE SET cert_time=excluded.cert_time;", to_db)
```

[UPSERT Parsing Ambiguity](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_UPSERT.html)

Comment: The ambiguity arises in an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement and not in an `INSERT ... VALUES ...` statement for which a WHERE clause is invalid.